# DroboPro ISCSI Connection - Connection has limited or no connectivity in Windows 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003, iscsi, drobo

I have a DroboPro
I've connected the device directly via USB and it works fine.

If i connect the ethernet cable directly from the 2nd Network card on my host machine, to the DroboPro (in order to use ISCSI) then it doesn't seem to connect-
I get a "Acquiring Network Address" message, on the network icon...
This eventially gives up and I get "This connection has limited or no connectivity"

I've set the Drobo to use DHCP (obtain address automatically)

I'm using Windows 2003 on the host machine, microsoft iscsi initiator (not that it can get this far yet!)

Comment: This site is for Professional Administrators, please see [FAQ](http://serverfault.com/faq) for more information. [SuperUser](http://superuser.com) is the site for casual computer users.

Comment: it's attached to a Windows Server 2003 SERVER. Not really fitting for a "casual" computer user.
Thanks

Comment: I think Chris is trying to say you're having a very basic networking issue and has nothing to do with "servers" but two peers. You need to set a static IP address on both the Drobo and the second NIC on your host. You need to make sure this does not conflict with your primary NIC's network. So if your primary NIC is 192.168.1.0/24 then  you need to adjust the third octet for this dedicated network, say 192.168.2.0/24

Comment: as Tom pointed out, I was trying to be nice and avoid saying you have a *very simple* configuration problem that any professional should know better. The OS is irrelevant in this case, it's quite obvious you don't know much about configuring network interfaces. Also, you've got a 42% accept rate, you should work on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably configure both the NIC and the Drobo with static IPs from the 1918 range. Alternately you could configure the server as a DHCP server, but this is going to add a lot of completely needless complexity.

Answer (score 1):

The default iSCSI configuration of the DroboPro is marked "Automatically configure (Default)" in the Drobo Dashboard utility.  This doesn't mean DHCP but instead resorts to using Zeroconf addresses (169.254.0.0/16).  In a point-to-point configuration such as yours, you have two choices:

1) Leave the Drobo Pro in the "Default" network configuration and configure your network adapter for DHCP.  The DHCP client in Windows will eventually timeout and you should receive a 169.254.X.X address for the network adapter.  The Drobo Dashboard utility should eventually find the DroboPro (could take a few minutes) and make an iSCSI connection.

2) Connect the DroboPro to your Windows system via USB and setup a static IP address on the DroboPro.  Then, statically configure you second network adapter for an IP address within the same subnet.  Restart your Windows system, remove the USB cable, and wait patiently for the Drobo Dashboard to find your DroboPro and make an iSCSI connection.

The benefit of the latter configuration is that you lose the "limited or no connectivity" message for your NIC.  If you're impatient and don't want to wait for Drobo Dashboard to find you DroboPro then you can setup the connection through the MS iSCSI Initiator in the control panel when you're using static IP addresses.

Dave